prove : $(1+x)^p +(1-x)^p \le 2^{p-1} (1+x^p)$ for all $p \ge 2$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$
prove :  $(1+x)^p +(1-x)^p \leq 2^{p-1} (1+x^p)$ for all $p \geq 2$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$.
See image:

This function is neither convex nor lower convex in it's domain. Meanwhile, as p could be decimal number， I can't use Binomial theorem. Is there any elementary way to prove this inequation?
(except for expand the Binomial theorem to decimal number)
